# Error says cocoapods is not installed after installation

Tags: ios, xcode, android-studio, flutter, cocoapods

I get this error when I try to run my flutter app on Macbook Pro:

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install:
sudo gem install cocoapods

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

This is my first attempt to run this app on a mac. I have installed cocoapods and the simulator I have is iPhone 12 Pro Max - 14.3. I am doing this in Android Studio.

I am new to macs and this has been a lengthy task trying to get this to run on mac. Any suggestions?

Comment: I had trouble trying to use the Catalina XCode and ruby install cocoapods.  I ended up installing the brew version of ruby, and with *that* install cocoapods.  Getting the PATH right is half the battle. :)

Answer (score 0):

Run pod update in your pod file and clean the flutter project and try to run

command for pod update

```
pod update
```

command for flutter clean

```
flutter clean
```

Comment: That didn't work. I still get the same error message.